# Vue, Webpack, DC.js, and Finally Crossfilter

Tags: javascript, d3.js, webpack, crossfilter

I'm trying to build a proof of concept application that uses DC.js to bring in some static data and visualize it. We've decided to use Vue.js as our framework and Webpack as our build tool. I have included D3.js, Crossfilter, and DC.js in the base config.

```
resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.vue'],
    fallback: [path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')],
    alias: {
      'src': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
      'assets': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets'),
      'components': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components'),
      'd3': path.resolve(__dirname, '../bower_components/d3/d3.min.js'),
      'crossfilter': path.resolve(__dirname, '../bower_components/crossfilter/crossfilter.min.js'),
      'dc': path.resolve(__dirname, '../bower_components/dcjs/dc.js') // using unminified version to look at exactly where the error is coming from
    }
}
```

And in the file with the actual visualization components like so.

```
var d3 = require('d3')
var cf = require('crossfilter')
var crossfilter = cf.crossfilter
var dc = require('dc')
```

However DC.js requires crossfilter to work and it hangs on the first instance of of a call to crossfilter within the context of DC.js. Further more after I load the page I can no longer access `crossfilter` in the console however I can access `D3`. What is bringing D3.js in as a global require that isn't bringing crossfilter in as one?

Is there some configuration that I'm overlooking here?

Comment: Could you use `{externals: 'crossfilter': 'crossfilter'}` and add `bower_components`to your list of resolve directories (https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-modulesdirectories)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So getting Crossfilter and DC.js to work with webpack and vue is possible. I had to make modifications to the DC.js source to get it work.

1. In `webpack.base.conf.js` you'll need to add the following to module exports.

   `plugins: [
     new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
       d3: 'd3',
       crossfilter: 'crossfilter',
       dc: 'dc'
     })
   ]`

This makes these three libraries available globally. Without requiring them.

2. If Like me you were using ESlint you'll need to add the following to `eslintrc.js` to have it ignore the fact that you're not requiring these files.

   `'globals': {
       'd3': true,
       'dc': true,
       'crossfilter': true
     }`
3. Finally in DC.js right after the `'use strict';` declaration you'll need to set up crossfilter.

   `var crossfilter = crossfilter.crossfilter;`

While this isn't a perfect answer it at least has me able to render charts. Now if I could figure out how to redefine the global Crossfilter package as crossfilter.crossfilter I would feel like I had a complete answer.

Comment: Can u post  changes u made to dc.js to work with Vuejs. Can you post the sample project on jsfiddle?